# Blackberry: Video player with labels and button

Tags: blackberry, video, layer

I want to create a Screen in my app where there will be a video playing on the screen and there will be buttons and labels on the video screen like below.

[image]

How to implement that? Can you give some sample code or idea? Is it possible to implement multiple layers in one screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible on pre OS7.0 devices. For OS7.0 devices you can use `ComponentCanvas` class.

Check this info from RIM

> Layering UI elements
>
> You can place UI components on top of other UI components using the
>   ComponentCanvas class. Unlike AbsoluteFieldManager, which provides
>   similar functionality, a ComponentCanvas is drawn on top of other
>   fields and managers on a screen, like a video or camera field. You can
>   add standard UI components, such as labels, buttons, and drop-down
>   lists, to ComponentCanvas. For example, you can use a ComponentCanvas
>   to display a series of buttons on top of a video field or camera
>   field.
>
> ComponentCanvas is found in the net.rim.device.api.ui.container
>   package.

Comment: Is it possible to show labels and buttons under the video? If it is, how it possible? I am searched for it, but failed to find out any help from web.